# Problems with segmentation fault and matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a program that reads a pgm file, stores the pixel values of the image within the matrix `img`, dynamically allocated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int height, width; // variables for the image height and width

typedef struct query {
    int x; // coordinate x of the position in which the user touched the image
    int y; // coordinate y of the position in which the user touched the image
    int crit; // criterion to be considered in segmentation
} queries;

void storeImage (FILE** fil, int** img) { // function that reads and stores the image in a matrix

    char trash; // variable that stores the content of 1st and 3rd line

    trash = fgetc(*fil);
    trash = fgetc(*fil);
    fscanf (*fil, "%d", &width);
    fscanf (*fil, "%d", &height);

    img = malloc (height * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        img[i] = malloc (width * sizeof(int));
    }
    fscanf (*fil, "%d", &img[0][0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) { // for that fills the matrix img
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            fscanf (*fil, "%d", &img[i][j]);
        }
    }

}

void verifyQuery (int x, int y, int c, int rep, int seg_regnum, int** img, float avg) {
    printf("%d ", img[x][y]);

}

int main (void) {

    FILE* fil = NULL;
    fil = fopen(test1.pgm, "r");
    if (fil == NULL) {
        printf("erro.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int** img; // pointer to the matrix that represents the image

    storeImage(&fil, img);

    int k; // number of queries to the input image
    scanf("%d ", &k);

    queries q;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) { // for to input the coordinates and criterion
        scanf("%d %d %d", &q.x, &q.y, &q.crit);
        float avg = 0;
        verifyQuery (q.x, q.y, q.crit, 0, i + 1, img, avg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything runs perfectly until I try to run `verifyQuery ()`. The program stores succesfully the content of the file inside the matrix `img`.
However, when I try to access `img` in `verifyQuery ()`, I get a segmentation fault for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to use a debugger (or some `printf`s to check value of `img` before, while and after the call to `storeImage()`.

Comment: @alk I did this, it works normally

Comment: You did what? What is working normally. And what do you consider "normally" in this context?

Comment: You need to either initialize `img` in `main`, or else pass its address to a function (i.e., pass an `int ***`) to initialize it for you.  Or have `storeImage` return `img` as its return value (this is probably the easiest solution for your case).

Comment: @alk Before coming here, I've verified what's stored in ```img``` with printf. Each pixel (x,y) is stored in img[x][y] as I expected. That's why i said that everything runs perfectly until I try to run ```verifyQuery ()```

Comment: Did you do this test inside `storeImage()` or elsewhere?

Comment: @sabonet You're confusing luck with something that will reliably work.  You're rolling dice with values left in registers and on the stack, and using that to justify the claim that everything runs perfectly.

Comment: OT: No need to pass the address of the file-pointer. Inside `storeImage()` make `fil` be a `FILE*`, make all `(*fil)` be `fil` and pass in `fil`.

Comment: "*when I try to access [...] `seg_img`*" What is `seg_img`?

Comment: @alk ```seg_img``` was another matrix that I removed because it wasn't relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What am I doing wrong?*

C is pass by value. So the address stored in `img` inside `storeImage()` is not passed up to the caller of `storeImage()`.

To prove this in `main()` change

```
  int** img;
```

to be

```
  int** img = NULL;
```

and right after the call to `storeImage()` add

```
  if (NULL == img)
  {
    fprintf(stderr ,"img is NULL\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```